# XML serialisation namespace on the wrong element

Tags: c#, xml

I'm posting XML to an API which has been serialised from a C# class at my end, everything looks correct apart from where a particular namespace is when the XML is generated but I am not sure why.

I need the `a` namespace to be be on the `appointmentAvailability` element. Ignore the escape backslashes that's just because I copied the xml out of the visual studio debugger.

Where am I going wrong?

**function to test**

```
    var a = new AppointmentAvailability
    {
        TimeSlot = "AM"

    };
    var aa = new AppointmentAvailabilityContainer();
    aa.appointmentAvailability = a;
    var nd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    nd.Add("a", "http://maindomain/Appointments");
    var x = XmlManager.SerializeThis<AppointmentAvailabilityContainer>(aa,nd);
    var checkappointmentavailability = FluidWeb.CheckAppointmentAvailability(a);
```

**generic serialise function**

```
public static string SerializeThis<T>(object obj, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                string xml = "";
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

                foreach (var item in dictionary)
                {
                    xsn.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    xs.Serialize(ms, obj, xsn);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    xd.Load(ms);
                    xml = xd.InnerXml;
                }
                return xml;
            }
            catch(XmlException x)
            {
                var xml = "Could not serialise.";
                return xml;
            }
        }
```

**classes**

```
[XmlRoot("AppointmentAvailability", Namespace = "http://maindomain")]
    public class AppointmentAvailabilityContainer
    {
        [XmlElement("appointmentAvailability")]
        public AppointmentAvailability appointmentAvailability { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot("appointmentAvailability", Namespace = "http://maindomain/Appointments")]
    [XmlType("a")]
    public class AppointmentAvailability
    {

        [XmlElement("TimeSlot")]
        public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
    }
```

**xml generated**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<AppointmentAvailability xmlns:a=\"http://maindomain/Appointments\" xmlns=\"http://maindomain">
<appointmentAvailability>
<a:TimeSlot>AM</a:TimeSlot>
</appointmentAvailability>
</AppointmentAvailability>
```

**xml trying to achieve**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<AppointmentAvailability  xmlns=\"http://maindomain">
<appointmentAvailability xmlns:a=\"http://maindomain/Appointments\">
<a:TimeSlot>AM</a:TimeSlot>
</appointmentAvailability>
</AppointmentAvailability>
```

Comment: The two pieces of XML you have posted are logically equivalent. If whatever you're sending this XML to is falling over, complain to them that they're not processing XML correctly.

Comment: So it doesn't matter where the `xmlns:a` appears, providing that it's above the child?

Comment: More that it has to be an an *enclosing* element, rather than above. E.g. if it was declared on another element that was a *sibling* to `TimeSlot`, that would not work, even if the sibling is above. All it says is "within this element, I want to associate *this* prefix with *this* namespace". It's valid (but odd) to declare a namespace and not use the prefix at all. Also, note that the decision on what prefixes to use (here, `a`) is a *local* decision within your XML. The same document with `xmlns:b=\"http://maindomain/Appointments\"` and a `<b:TimeSlot>` element would also be logically same.

Comment: Yes local decision to match their API guide, when posting, as when using GET all of the XML namespaces I'm not fussed about. Thank you very much for the explanation!